# QtQuickPaintedItem rotated with an orientation quaternion

Tags: qt, rotation

I'm trying to make a simple QML component that rotates an item by a given quaternion.

I get the quaternion from ArUco in the OGRE Quaternion type and I apply it to a QMatrix4x4. I then get the QTransform from the matrix and try applying it to the painter. Unfortunately the effect is quite different:

```
void Marker::paint(QPainter *painter) 
{ 
  QMatrix4x4 mat; 
  QQuaternion q = QQuaternion(0.883290,-0.128302,0.436779,-0.112081); 
  mat.rotate(q);

  QRect rect = QRect(width()/4,height()/4,width()/2,height()/2);

  painter->setTransform(mat.toTransform()); 
  painter->fillRect(rect, Qt::red); 
}
```

The result is:

[image]

And it's supposed to look like this:

[image]

**UPDATE#1**: I think the problem is that I rotate the matrix with an orientation quaternion, while I probably should apply that orientation in some other manner? I don't fully understand Quaternions, can someone explain if that's a mistake?

**UPDATE#2**: I read up more about it and it does turn out that orientation is a rotation relative to a reference position. I do think I have such position, I'm not sure how to apply it.

Answer (score 1):

The code above is right, the thing with my example is that it's actually a cube not a simple rectangle and the result is the front wall of the cube. So basicly all I had to do was:

```
QQuaternion q = QQuaternion(0.883290,-0.128302,0.436779,-0.112081); 
QQuaternion y90 = QQuaternion(sqrt(0.5),sqrt(0.5),0,0); // 90 degree around x quaternion

QQuaternion wyn = q*y90;
wyn = wyn.normalized(); // not needed in this case but if you want to rotate for say 180 degrees it's needed
```